# Prevent Html data behaving like script data

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have multiple HTML forms running on my application and I have found some issues like when I insert any code in Javascript code inside the input fields then it the values get submitted but when I open the same data on view mode then it behaves like the script not like the values.
for example, I have this form:

```
<form>
   <input type='text' name='name'/>
</form>
```

and now if I add any script data

```
<script>
   alert("hello world");
</script>
```

submitting the form works fine but opening the record on view mode shows an alert box.
while I am opening the data then I am entertaining this as simple HTML text not on the input fields this is looking like a simple text
for example:

```
<span>
     <script>alert('hello world')</script>
</span>
```

what can I do to prevent the data from behaving like the script?

Comment: The problem isn't the submission or storage per se (albeit filtering would be one option), but in how it's output later on (lack of escaping).

Comment: You can have an hidden object like:
<div id="mode" class="hidden">form</div>
This element you can use to detect the beheibor. 
<script>if(document.getElementById("myList").textContent==='form'){alert('It a form!');}</script>